# Why does vi and sudo vi give me different version of vim?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

The default version of vi that comes with Ubuntu Hardy is the 7.1 or 7.2. So I installed vim 7.3 from sources.

Then to make it convenient I added this to my `.bashrc`

```
alias vi='vim'
```

In order to let the 7.3 vim overwrite the vi which is old version. This works fine for me, but when I add sudo before that, something like

```
sudo vi /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

It gaves me the old version

Anyone give me a clue why is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*vi* 7.2 and 7.3 **do not exist**. There is only [*vi* 050325](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) and [*vim* 7.2](http://www.vim.org/download.php), two entirely separate programs with similar features. If you want *vim*, type `vim`.

---

The reason your alias does not work is because aliases are expanded by your shell, and the shell does not know what each program will be doing – it sees "`sudo`" as the command and "`vi myfile`" as arguments, and only attempts to expand the first word, "`sudo`", without daring to touch the arguments.

You **can** tell *bash* to expand aliases following certain commands, by adding an alias such as: (note the space inside quotes is required)

```
alias sudo="sudo "
```

The space will tell bash that the first word after "`sudo`" is a command that should be expanded – for example, `"sudo vi ..."` to "`sudo vim ...`" will work now.

---

The answers telling about `/root/.bashrc` are incorrect for several reasons. First, `sudo` executes the given command *without* running a shell. (This can be changed by using `sudo -s cmd` or `sudo -i cmd`, but if neither option is given, the default behavior is to execute the command directly, without a shell.)

Second, bash will only expand aliases when run in *interactive* mode, not when run as `bash -c cmd`, which is what `sudo` would use. (Again, this can be changed, but the default setting is to only expand aliases interactively.)

Comment: well, deleted mine.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are per-user. Your first command assigned the alias only to your non-privileged user, and when you use sudo it's running as root. You should create the alias for the root user too.

Answer (score 1):

When run `sudo vi`,

1. `sudo` loads `/root/.bashrc` file. And it decides whether its an alias or original one (wich is `vim`).
2. The `vi` part then parses `/root/.vimrc` if it exists. Otherwise `/etc/vim/vimrc`

Comment: `sudo` by itself does not process `.bashrc` or expand aliases; those two features are part of `bash`, which `sudo` does not run (it executes the command directly).